# Convert Keras MobileNet model to TFLite with 8-bit quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have used Keras to finetune MobileNet v1. Now I have `model.h5` and I need to convert it to TensorFlow Lite to use it in Android app.

I use TFLite conversion [script](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples) `tflite_convert`. I can convert it without quantization but I need more performance so I need to make quantization.

If I run this script:

```
tflite_convert --output_file=model_quant.tflite \
 --keras_model_file=model.h5 \
 --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
 --input_arrays=input_1 \
 --output_arrays=predictions/Softmax \
 --mean_values=128 \
 --std_dev_values=127 \
 --input_shape="1,224,224,3"
```

It fails:

> F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1634] Array
>   conv1_relu/Relu6, which is an input to the DepthwiseConv operator
>   producing the output array conv_dw_1_relu/Relu6, is lacking min/max
>   data, which is necessary for quantization. If accuracy matters, either
>   target a non-quantized output format, or run quantized training with
>   your model from a floating point checkpoint to change the input graph
>   to contain min/max information. If you don't care about accuracy, you
>   can pass --default_ranges_min= and --default_ranges_max= for easy
>   experimentation.\nAborted (core dumped)\n"

If I use `default_ranges_min` and `default_ranges_max` (called as "dummy-quantization"), it works but it is only for debugging performance without accuracy as it is described in error log.

So what I need to do to make Keras model correctly quantizable? Do I need to find best `default_ranges_min` and `default_ranges_max`? How? Or it is about changes in Keras training phase?

Library versions:

```
Python 3.6.4
TensorFlow 1.12.0
Keras 2.2.4
```

Comment: Discussion on TensorFlow github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tensorflow does not provide the tooling for post-training per layer quantization in flatbuffer (tflite) yet, but only in protobuf. The only available way now is to introduce [fakeQuantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/fake_quant_with_min_max_vars) layers in your graph and re-train / fine-tune your model on the train or a calibration set. This is called "[Quantization-aware training](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize)".

Once the fakeQuant layers are introduced, then you can feed the training set and TF is going to use them on Feed-Forward as simulated quantisation layers (fp-32 datatypes that represent 8-bit values) and back-propagate using full precision values. This way, you can get back the accuracy loss that caused by quantization.

In addition, the fakeQuant layers are going to capture the ranges per layer or per channel through moving average and store them in min / max variables.

Later, you can extract the graph definition and get rid of the fakeQuant nodes through `freeze_graph` tool.

Finally, the model can be fed into tf_lite_converter (cross-fingers it won't brake) and extract the u8_tflite with captured ranges.

A very good white-paper, explaining all these is provided by Google here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08342.pdf

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for help. I was quite confused if I trained before in TensorFlow for example `graph.pb`, I was able to use `tools/quantization/quantize_graph.py` with quantization option. And Keras works on top of TensorFlow. So I thought it is possible to do the same. But I guess, the output of this script is not fully quantized model which TFLite needs to work with, am I right?

Comment: 'quantize_graph.py' is a legacy tool. Use 
 graph_transforms 'https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md'

Comment: Is there any way how to add fakeQuantization layers in Keras?

Comment: I think this is TBD by Google ... I haven't seen this yet.